# I do not understand the definition of Hopf fibrations?

Tags: differential-topology

How i go about understanding why Hopf fibration is a map,i did not understand the **3-sphere** to **2 sphere** concept?Could you please explain??

Comment: Do you know the meaning of fibration?

Comment: There's a lot missing from our question. Without more context from you, we have no idea what you do not understand, making it very hard to answer this question, and so attracting close votes. Do you know the formula for the Hopf fibration? What specifically about the formula confuses you? See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for general information on improving your question, and specifically [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) for how to avoid "I have no clue" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: If the quaternion $w$ commutates with every pure imaginary, then $w$ is real.If in addition, $w \in \mathbb{S}^{3}$, then $w = \pm 1$

Proposition : There is a continuous surjective homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{S}^{3} 
\longrightarrow \text{SO}(3)$ with $\text{Ker}(\varphi) = \lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace$

Use this to set the map $h : \mathbb{S}^{3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^{2}$ by putting $h(u) = u^{-1}.i.u = \varphi_{u}(i)$.

1) the application h is continuous, surjective and;

2) $h(u) = h(v)  \Leftrightarrow u.v^{-1}$ commutes with i, this is, if, and only if, $w = u.v^{-1} = a + bi$ is a common complex number.

It follows that the equivalence relation induced in $\mathbb{S}^{3}$ is the same as that defined $\mathbb{CP}^{1}$ as the quotient space.

By passing the quotient we obtain a homeomorphism $H : \mathbb{CP}^{1} \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^{2}$. It follows that $H$ fibration is a locally trivial fiber with typical fiber $\mathbb{S}^{1}$

Remark : I do not know if I understood your question, but I hope I have helped.

For more details, see the references:

I) Fundamental Groups and Covering Spaces by Elon Lages Lima (propostion 14, Chapter 3,in my edition )

II) Basic Algebraic Topology. Anant R. Shastri (Hopf Fibration)